# Recursive function that returns the number of numbers greater then the first index of an array

Tags: c, recursion

Recursive function that returns the number of numbers greater then the first index of an array

I've got a function that solves the problem but I'm not sure if it is the correct way to write the recursive function

```
int greaterThanFistIndex(int *v,int n){
    int a;
    if(n == 1){
        return 0;
    }else{
        a = greaterThanFistIndex(v,n-1);
        if(v[0] < v[n-1]){
            a++;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

the output of [3,5,1,6] should be 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure if it is the correct way to write the recursive function

The code looks *OK* yet it breaks the spirit of using recursion.<sup>1</sup>

Such code could readily be done with a simple loop instead of `n` recursive calls.

```
int greaterThanFistIndex_iterate(const int *v,int n){
  count = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i<n; i++) {
    if (v[i] > v[0]) count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

---

Could *could* halve the problem at each step.  At least the would have only log2(n) recursion depth rather than `n` as in OP's code.

```
static int greaterThanFistIndex_r_helper(const int *v,int n, int first){
  if (n <= 0) {
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    return *v > first;
  }
  int first_half = n/2; 
  int second_half = n - first_half; 
  return greaterThanFistIndex_r_helper(v, first_half, first) +  
      greaterThanFistIndex_r_helper(v + first_half, second_half, first);
}

int greaterThanFistIndex_r(const int *v,int n){
  if (n <= 0) return 0;
  return greaterThanFistIndex_r_helper(v+1, n, *v);
}
```

Some compilers will detect OP's construct and perform tail end recursion optimization yet I see a simple loop a better approach.

---

Use recursion when it makes sense.  Use a loop when possible.

Note: better to use `size_t` than `int` for array size and indexing. (not shown here)

---

<sup>1</sup> 
Code fails for `n <= 0`.
A better function signature would be `size_t greaterThanFistIndex(const int *v, size_t n)`